# Input validation using PHP and Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to validate an user input with ajax. It is the first time I use Ajax and I got stuck. If the input is correct I still get an error message and I don't know why.

I get as an error 'Subtax error in the jquery file'. What do I do wrong?
Thank you in advance.

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputName">Your name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="inputName" class="form-control" id="inputName"   placeholder="Name">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail">Your e-mail</label>
                    <input type="text" name="inputEmail" class="form-control" id="inputEmail"    placeholder="E-mail">
                </div>                    

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputMess">Your message for us</label>
                    <textarea name="inputMess" class="form-control" id="inputMess"></textarea>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
              </form>

              <div id='mess'></div>
```

PHP:

```
 <?php 

  sleep(1);

  $mail_reg = '/^(?i)(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9] {1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/';

$return = array();
$mesaj = '';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {


    if (empty($_POST['inputName']) || is_numeric($_POST['inputName'])) {

      $mesaj = "Please enter your name!";
      $return['error'] = true;
      $return['msg'] = 'oops'.$mesaj;
      echo json_encode($return);
      exit();

    } elseif (empty($_POST['inputEmail']) || !preg_match($mail_reg, $_POST['inputEmail'])) {

      $mesaj = "Please enter your e-mail!";
      $return['error'] = true;
      $return['msg'] = 'oops'.$mesaj;
      echo json_encode($return);
      exit();

    } elseif (empty($_POST['inputMess'])) {

      $mesaj = "Please tell us something";
      $return['error'] = true;
      $return['msg'] = 'oops'.$mesaj;
      echo json_encode($return);
      exit();

    } else {

      $return['error'] = false;
      $return['msg'] = 'Thank you for getting in touch. We will contact you!';
      echo json_encode($return);
       exit();

    }
  }


 ?>
```

JavaScript:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
 var email_reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/i;   

$('form').submit(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  if ($('#inputName').val() == '' || $('#inputName').val().length < 2 || !isNaN($('#inputName').val())) {

    alert('Please enter your name');

  } else if (!email_reg.test($('#inputEmail').val())) {

    alert('Please enter a valid e-mail adress');

  } else if ($('#inputMess').val() == '' || !isNaN($('#inputMess').val())) {

    alert('Please tell us something');

  } else {

    var formData = $('form').serialize();
    submitForm(formData);

  }

})


function submitForm(formData) {

    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: $('form').action,
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 7000,
        success: function(data) {


                $('#mess').text(data.msg);

        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {


                $('#mess').text('A communication error occured');

        },
        complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {

            //$('form')[0].reset();

        }

    })
}


  })
```

Comment: PS: I use WAMP Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be some problem with your jquery file inclusion. Your code is working absolutely fine with me. I tried your code by saving it in a new php file as follows.

```
<?php 

  sleep(1);

  $mail_reg = '/^(?i)(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9] {1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/';

$return = array();
$mesaj = '';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {


    if (empty($_POST['inputName']) || is_numeric($_POST['inputName'])) {

      $mesaj = "Please enter your name!";
      $return['error'] = true;
      $return['msg'] = 'oops'.$mesaj;
      echo json_encode($return);
      exit();

    } elseif (empty($_POST['inputEmail']) || !preg_match($mail_reg, $_POST['inputEmail'])) {

      $mesaj = "Please enter your e-mail!";
      $return['error'] = true;
      $return['msg'] = 'oops'.$mesaj;
      echo json_encode($return);
      exit();

    } elseif (empty($_POST['inputMess'])) {

      $mesaj = "Please tell us something";
      $return['error'] = true;
      $return['msg'] = 'oops'.$mesaj;
      echo json_encode($return);
      exit();

    } else {

      $return['error'] = false;
      $return['msg'] = 'Thank you for getting in touch. We will contact you!';
      echo json_encode($return);
       exit();

    }
  }


 ?> 
<html>
<head>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputName">Your name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="inputName" class="form-control" id="inputName"   placeholder="Name">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail">Your e-mail</label>
                    <input type="text" name="inputEmail" class="form-control" id="inputEmail"    placeholder="E-mail">
                </div>                    

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputMess">Your message for us</label>
                    <textarea name="inputMess" class="form-control" id="inputMess"></textarea>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
              </form>

              <div id='mess'></div>
              <script>
              $(document).ready(function() {
              var email_reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/i;   

$('form').submit(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  if ($('#inputName').val() == '' || $('#inputName').val().length < 2 || !isNaN($('#inputName').val())) {

    alert('Please enter your name');

  } else if (!email_reg.test($('#inputEmail').val())) {

    alert('Please enter a valid e-mail adress');

  } else if ($('#inputMess').val() == '' || !isNaN($('#inputMess').val())) {

    alert('Please tell us something');

  } else {

    var formData = $('form').serialize();
    submitForm(formData);

  }

})


function submitForm(formData) {

    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: $('form').action,
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 7000,
        success: function(data) {


                $('#mess').text(data.msg);

        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {


                $('#mess').text('A communication error occured');

        },
        complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {

            //$('form')[0].reset();

        }

    })
}


  })
              </script>
              </body>
              </html>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I tried chainging the jqury but I still have same problem:      Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a jquery.min.js:4
2

Comment: Are you getting 'Thank you for getting in touch. We will contact you!'  ?

Comment: I have added a screenshot to my answer, please check.

Comment: yes. It is working for you. What webserver do you use. I use wamp 2.5

Comment: I am using xampp 1.8.2, try copying the above code and pasting it in a new php file and test in wamp itself.

Comment: I did. Indeed is working. Now I am trying to find out where my error comes from

Comment: Can you send me the code you used previously in the manner i pasted my whole php file code, so I can help you to figure out the error.

Comment: Should i send you my files via gmail?

Comment: Yeah that would help my mail id: kavuri.praveen@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Try add `header('Content-Type: application/x-javascript');` in php before outputing the json string.

Comment: no...still not ok. In Firefox I get "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"  and this is the JSON  "{"msg":"Thank you for getting in touch. We will contact you!"}"